# Splitting a string of numbers after every 5th number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm formatting some code for a Baudot translator and the program needs to take in 10001 11001 the same as it would 1000111001, for example.

How would I go about doing this?

```
sentence=[]
if " " in Baudot=True:
    null
else:

codingSeq=Baudot.split(" ")
for letter in codingSeq:
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. What is your actual question? Also, what does `if " " in Baudet = True:` even mean? Perhaps you meant `if  " " in Baudet == True:` -- but why the spurious comparison of a Boolean with a Boolean to get a Boolean? Just use `if  " " in Baudet:`

Comment: basically, if there are spaces in the string, don't do anything. otherwise, split every 5th character

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to convert a binary sequence into a Baudot format. If that is the case then this should work for you:

```
  bstr = "100011001101101"
  baudot = " ".join([bstr[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(bstr),5)])
```

Modifying your code:

```
def bsplit(seq):
    flag = True
    for i in seq.split(" "):
        if len(i)!=5:
            flag = False
    if flag:
        return seq
    else:
        seq = "".join(seq.split(" ")) #To remove all existing spaces
        return " ".join([seq[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(seq),5)]) #To reformat the sequence
```

You can now call

```
 bsplit("10001100111010101")
```

Comment: You would also have to make sure the length of your string is without spaces is a multiple of 5. For which you can do something like:

    len(''.join(seq.split(' ')))%5==0

Answer (score 0):

yes, Saravana Kumar answer can be made simpler by just using the `len(seq) % 5 == 0` as the only test needed

```
def bsplit(seq):
    if len(seq) % 5 == 0:
        return ' '.join(seq[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(seq), 5))
    return seq
```

with a inline if-else we can have a single `return`, I added paren to allow line breaks to somewhat restore readability after making it a 'one-liner'

```
def bsplit(seq):
    return (seq if len(seq) % 5
                else ' '.join(seq[i:i+5]
                              for i in range(0, len(seq), 5)))
```